# include tailwind css in bundle js

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, tailwind-css

How could I include tailwind css in bundle js ?

this is the an example with vue 3 and tailwind 3 https://github.com/musashiM82/vue-webpack.

running  `npm run build` , it creates 3 files:

- app.js
- ABOUTPAGE.js
- app.6cba1802.css

I want to include app.6cba1802.css into app.js, so the result should be:

- app.js
- ABOUTPAGE.js

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the css.extract option from vue cli :

https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#css-extract

```
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  configureWebpack: {
    ...
  },
  css: {
       extract: false
  }
});
```